# Adding a static value to an array that is saved in the database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I have a database table named **articles** and a corresponding Model named **Article**. 
Say, table articles have columns id, body, created_by

In the ArticleController controller I can save to DB as such:

```
    $data = request()->validate(['name'=>'required|min:5|max:10']);

    $article = new \App\Article();
    $article->name = request('name');
    $article->created_by = 1;
    $article->save();

    return redirect()->back();
```

Which I would like to shorten to:

```
    \App\Article::create(request()->validate(['name'=>'required|min:5:max:10']));
    return redirect()->back();
```

My problem is, the value for the column **created_by** will not be coming from the POST request, instead this value will be coming maybe from a session or a dynamic global variable.

How do I add the **created_by** column in the shortened version?

Comment: please look up answers and if anyone is correct please mark as solution, if not please comment why is not a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Model Observers to listen to creating event and assign the created_at from the auth or session.

Checkout 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events

Comment: Good point, but this would complicate a process I am trying to solve. My question is more trivial, I can always use the first option I stated which is more simple. I was just wondering if I can simplify it further.

Answer (score 0):

Several solution exists. Firstly as Alex Jose's response, you can use observer. You can use observer or events (in model). Secondly, you can default value on your table column. But why? your first way is very well. More readable, more expandable. Use the first way if you want to good developer. If you want to short your code, try this:

```
$data = request()->validate(['name'=>'required|min:5|max:10']);

\App\Article::create(array_merge($data,['created_by'=>1]));
```

Comment: Is this helps to you?

Comment: I tried the code, it did not work. But I get your point of using the first option, I was just wondering whether the 2nd option is a possibility.